# 404 showing index.php removing time in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, url-routing

Already working project i will download and up to another server change all thing but show 404 and index.php add to config working

This is my `.htacess` file below :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

i try other rewriting code but not working  my config file

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

but all time show 404 why locally not working

Comment: set like this : ;`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/app_folder/';
$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: @pradeep locally i will try this but above code in server locally not working why ?

Comment: you have to set it for localhost environment , for server set server path for local u have to set local path

Comment: @pradeep not working in locally why i do for this up to a new server

Comment: actually i thought it is not working in localhost, for another server give server name to base url

Comment: i will do that but 404 show i and add  index.php  in config index part that working

Comment: is you app installed on subfolder of webroot?

Comment: no sub folder its main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` file should be like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and in your `config.php`

```
/* for server */
$config['base_url'] = 'http://silhouetteframes.in/';

 /* for localhost*/
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/app_folder/'; 
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: not working 404 show and object not found eroor show

Comment: for another server u have to provide server name like testing.com etc

Comment: i will host to a new domain

Comment: so then provide domain name to your base_url , what is your domain?

Comment: i will do that  add domain name in baseurl

Comment: ur base url should be like this :  `$config['base_url'] = 'http://silhouetteframes.in/';` and upload all file in `www` folder / in webroot, as in my answer

Comment: i will upload to public_html but i check all files in www folder that are same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177098/discussion-between-andrew-ghosh-and-pradeep).

Comment: `public_html`  and `www` are same thing , both r same belongs to web root

Comment: have u set `base_url` as in my answer and upload all files to `public_html` folder, pls let me know if u upload all the files

Comment: ya i will upload all files